# How to update a nested object in EdgeDB?

Tags: edgedb

Say I have a schema like this:

```
type Foo {
    required link bar -> Bar; 
}

type Bar {
    required property baz -> bool;
}
```

How do I, knowing the id of a `Foo` object, update a property of a `Baz` object it points to?
In other words, how do I update `Foo.bar.baz` value knowing `Foo`'s ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter based on the backlink like this:

```
select Bar filter .<bar.id = <uuid>'df492862-80aa-11ed-832e-e72d12452736';
```

Where `df492862-80aa-11ed-832e-e72d12452736` is the ID of your `Foo` object. That means you can update like this:

```
update Bar
  filter .<bar.id = <uuid>'df492862-80aa-11ed-832e-e72d12452736'
  set { baz := false };
```